# Crystal Report shows credential's popup after deployment and This issue occurs only when we turn off TLS 1.0 at server

Tags: asp.net, ssl, crystal-reports, tls1.2, tls1.0

- We have an issue of Crystal Report. Crystal Report shows credential's popup on server.

  This issue occurs only when we turn off TLS 1.0 at server If we turn on the TLS 1.0 then it is not displaying popup. It is also working properly at local.

  We need the solution when we turn off the TLS 1.0 on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drivers used for TLS 1.2 are different. You need to update your database connection to use the new drivers. If you have a lot of reports you can use a tool like this: http://r-tag.com/Pages/BlogPost/7